# Como fazer para que a TextView acompanhe a escrita

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, textview

preciso que o Textview acompanhe quando eu escrevo pois se isso não ocorre eu acabo escrevendo em baixo de teclado, eu ja dei um Up no textview porem ele é muito grande e vai acabar ficando em baixo mesmo.
como faço para que o textView acompanhei quando eu escrevo [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código que criei traduzindo de Objective-C para Swift funcionou para mim.

Eu não estou utilizando `scrollView` e ao invés de mover o `textView.frame`, estou usando `contentInset` para rastrear o cursor.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    registerForKeyboardNotification()
    textView.delegate = self
}

func registerForKeyboardNotification() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWasShown:"), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillBeHidden:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let info = aNotification.userInfo!
    let kbSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey])!.CGRectValue.size
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0)
    textView.contentInset = contentInsets
    textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    textView.contentInset = contentInsets
    textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Acredito ser bem próximo do que procuramos, funcionou para mim em Xcode 7 beta 4, espero que ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Recentemente tive um problema parecido e utilizei a biblioteca [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) para resolvê-lo. Essa biblioteca move as caixas de texto automaticamente para fora do teclado.

Para utilizá-la coloque os textViews dentro de um TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView, que extende UIScrollView. Pelo nib é só adicionar um objeto UIScrollView e mudar a classe (*Custom Class*) para TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.